# Cargar automaticamente un file en base datos

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda, estoy diseñando un videojuego en unity, pero va a guardar una imagen en un servidor, lo que hago es mediante unity abrir una pagina web que automaticamente toma la imagen de una carpeta de mi computadora y la guarda en un servidor, pero mi duda aqui es como puedo cargar de manera automatica la imagen de una carpeta para poderla mandar a la base datos, todo esto es en php y mysql.

---

lo que pasa es que si se usar php, html y mysql, pero no se sobre algun comando para extraer la imagen del directorio dinamico para poderlo subir a mysql, estoy usando esto para visualizar de manera dinamica:

```
$ruta = "img/"; // Indicar la ruta
    $filehandle = opendir($ruta); // Abrir archivos de la carpeta
    while ($file = readdir($filehandle)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
        {
            $tamanyo = GetImageSize($ruta . $file);             
            echo "<p><img src='$ruta$file' id='imagen'><br></p>\n";
        } 
    }
```

pero de aqui ya no se como poder guardar la imagen que esta siendo visualizada.
y no quiero usar un input de tipo file, porque lo tendria que subir de manera manual y lo que necesito es que todo este procedimiento lo haga de manera automatica sin intervernir en de ninguna manera

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas en tus preguntas solucionan tus dudas, recuerda marcaslas como solucionadas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es conceptual y no hay algo ya "Listo para USAR".

Pero respondiendo a tu pregunta lo estándar como en otros sistemas es que sepas el path físico en disco en donde guardas en el servidor estas imágenes; y en la base de datos guardar solo el nombre del archivo...

Ten en consideración que cada imagen que subas debes renombrarla y ese nuevo nombre debes usarlo en la base de datos y en el archivo; esto es importante para evitar la colisión de nombres de archivos...

para lograr esto tu pagina `html` debe tener un `input file`... y en `php` debes usar la super global `$_FILE` ... podras encontrar en internet distintos codigos para realizar esta azaña; si tienes algun problema sobre un error relacionado al codigo no dudes en traerlo en un nuevo post.